# Loop through a list of date strings: strptime outputs "Datetime.date(2011-7-5)" instead of (2011-7-5)

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, datetime

I have the following problem:

I have a list of date strings:

```
dates = ['11-07-05',
         '11-07-01',
         '11-07-03',
         '11-07-04', etc]
```

I want to convert them into date formats and i have used the following code:

```
from datetime import datetime as dt
dateFormat = [dt.strptime(item[1],"%y-%m-%d").date() for item in dates
```

this should output a new list in the following format:

```
dateFormat = [2011-7-5,
              2011-7-1,
              2011-7-3,
              2011-7-4]
```

but the output turns out to be:

```
dateFormat = [datetime.date(2011-7-5),
              datetime.date(2011-7-1),
              datetime.date(2011-7-3),
              datetime.date(2011-7-4)]
```

My question is: How can i format the date strings into date format without the "datetime.date"?

Comment: What language are you using? Please add the relevant tag.

Comment: I use python 2.7 :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to convert the string to datetime using [datetime.strptime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime) and then convert the datetime back to string using [datetime.strftime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.strftime)

```
from datetime import datetime as dt

dates = ['11-07-05', '11-07-01', '11-07-03', '11-07-04']

# Iterate through the dates
# Convert string to datetime using strptime 
# and then convert the datetime back to string using strftime
dateFormat = [dt.strptime(item,"%y-%m-%d").date().strftime('%Y-%m-%d') for item in dates]

print(dateFormat)
```

The output will be

```
['2011-07-05', '2011-07-01', '2011-07-03', '2011-07-04']
```